# How to obtain data by simple operation without loop?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data like:

```
      col1 col2 col3
1     1    0.1  0.4
2     1.4  0.6  9.4
...
2000  2.1  0.1  2.3
```

`data.shape=(2000,3)`. Set `moving_window=20`, `seq_len=100`, `seq_interval=10`, using the loop method to generate training samples:

```
start = 0
sample_counts = (data.shape[0]-moving_window)/moving_window
samples = []
for i in range(sample_counts):
    start += moving_window*i
    end = start + seq_len*seq_interval
    samples.append(data.iloc[start:end].values)
```

This method is low efficiency. I want to find a more efficient method like reshape(which is not suitable for this case) or other whole operations.

Comment: Please only use relevant tags (machine-learning removed).